# an indentation error?

Tags: haskell, monads, indentation

I think know how to use identantion in Haskell, but I has a problem in this code:

```
module TestTSPGA where 

import TSPGA -- in this we have the type used on the second function
import Data.List

main :: IO () 
main = do 
          contents <- readFile "aaaa.txt" 
          let s = map words (lines contents) 
          let cities = map stringsToCity s 

stringsToCity :: [String] -> City 
stringsToCity [c, x, y] = (read c, (read x, read y))
```

the error is the same of the n questions in StackOverflow, I tryed to fix this n times, but don't had sucess.

the error:

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\TestTSPGA.hs:11:10: error:

The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression

let cities = map stringsToCity s

I'm a begginer in haskell, when I think I can had learning anything, the language show me a new error.

Comment: This is not an indentation error. The problem is that you use a `IO` monad, but your last line is not a monadic line. Do you want to print something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't end a `do` block with a `let` (or a `x <- ...`): there must be something you want to do with that variable you are binding.

The easiest fix is to do nothing:

```
main = do 
   contents <- readFile "aaaa.txt" 
   let s = map words (lines contents) 
   let cities = map stringsToCity s 
   return ()
```

Surely you have some better idea about how to continue your `main`. E.g. you could `print cities`, or do more computation.

Comment: This is a very simple Test, like a debug, I have to study for  aplicate the functions in this code, I understood the explanation for the expression do, thanks!